# How to cut the values of variable after some string

Tags: vb.net

I have the following part of code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As  System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles  ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.Text

    Line = TextBox1.Text

    MsgBox(Line)

End Sub
```

While Line value for example is

```
  AIRC CEE – Air SMI Chennai - OM1  && ssh 20.20.20.6
```

What I need is the strings after the **&&**  only , so LINE variable will include only the strings after the &&.

for example

```
 MsgBox(Line)
```

Will print the

```
ssh 20.20.20.6
```

Comment: Is this question for VB6, VBA or VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, one of them is to use `Split` -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Try this:

```
Sub SplitTest()

Dim SplitLine As Variant

Line = "AIRC CEE – Air SMI Chennai - OM1  && ssh 20.20.20.6"

MsgBox (Line)

SplitLine = Split(Line, "&&")

MsgBox (SplitLine(1))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

VB

```
newString = Trim(MID(TextBox1.Text, InStrRev (TextBox1.Text, "&") +1, Len(TextBox1.Text) - InStrRev (TextBox1.Text, "&") +1)))
```

VB.NET

```
newString = TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("&") + 1).Trim()
```